# PHP/SQL - Won't Insert New User into Table

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, insert

My problem is that my script won't insert the new user info into my Database table. I have no clue why, I've been looking at this for nearly 3 hours on end, trying to find the problem, but I can't seem to locate it. Here's my script(SQLITE 3, by the way):

```
    $db = sqlite_open("../../kinz/kinz-db.sqlite", 0666, $sqlerr);

$query_login = sqlite_query($db, "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER = '$user'");
$result = sqlite_fetch_all($query_login, SQLITE_ASSOC);

$query_setId = sqlite_query($db, "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM USERS)", $sqlerr);
$result2 = sqlite_fetch_all($query_setId, SQLITE_ASSOC);
$ID = $result2[0][ID] + 1;

if (count($result) >= 1) {
    $_SESSION['regErr'] = "Username already in use";
    header("Location: register.php");
    exit();
} else {
    /*This is the registration query*/$query_register = sqlite_query($db, "INSERT INTO USERS (ID, USER, DISPLAY_NAME, PASS_ENC1, PASS_ENC2) VALUES ($ID, '$user', '$displayName', '$pass_enc1', '$pass_enc2')", $sqlerr);
}

if (!$query_register) {
    $_SESSION['regErr'] = $sqlerr;
    header("Location: register.php");
    exit();
} else {
    $_SESSION['regSuccess'] = true;
}
```

Comment: Any errors? I assume sqlite3 has error reporting features as well?

Comment: It does, and I have the errors being printed. But there's none; it's just an empty variable

Comment: you really should be able to narrow that down to a line or 2.

Comment: Doesn't PHP have function to get the last errors for sqlite3? Just like mysql_error or something? I don't see any of these in your code.

Comment: @Kinz: you have very little error checking going on... does `$db = sqlitee_open(...)` fail? does `$query_login = sqlite_query(...)` fail?  You *have* to do error checking; we can't do it for you.

Comment: I have. Why do you think I'm coming here.

Answer (score 1):

Since INSERT is a resultless SQL statement, you should probably use [sqlite_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-exec.php) instead of sqlite_query().

You should also report *what* error occurred if sqlite_query() or sqlite_exec() return FALSE.  You don't have to output to the user, but output to someplace where you can read it.  Currently you only store it in $_SESSION, which is probably hard to access.

Here's how I would write it:

```
$query_register = sqlite_exec($db, "INSERT INTO USERS 
    (ID, USER, DISPLAY_NAME, PASS_ENC1, PASS_ENC2) VALUES 
    ($ID, '$user', '$displayName', '$pass_enc1', '$pass_enc2')", $sqlerr);

if ($query_register === false) {
    error_log("Sqlite error in file ".__FILE__." on line ".__LINE__.": "
    . $sqlerr);
}
```

Also, I don't see that you're [escaping variables](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-escape-string.php) before interpolating them into your INSERT statement.  You need to be careful to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Or else upgrade to the SQLite3 API, which supports [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.prepare.php) with parameters.  That's much safer for protecting against SQL injection when writing dynamic queries.

[PDO_sqlite](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php) also supports prepared statements, I would recommend using PDO.